# Azure B2C User Attributes Claim - Unable to Save Claim?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, claims

I'm using Azure B2C. I have a custom claim I want include on profile edit. This is the built in user flow for Profile Edit (B2C_1_ProfileEdit).

I go to **Application claims**, select my claim, and click **Save** I get an error message

> "Unexpected error, please try again later"

No details were given in the error message.

What could this be? I'm not sure where to look to debug it? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you followed the docs.  Most common issues I've seen is people skipping edit AAD-Common technical profile.   Do you have any extension Attributes working already? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#get-extensions-apps-application-properties

Comment: These are not custom policies. I originally set it up with the out of the box defaults on the the signinout policy. I’m using my custom claim in the signinout and noticed I didn’t return some claims my app needs on profileedit and passwordreset. I tried added them and got this message.

Comment: I’ll take a look at the link. Maybe the xml for the claim got messed up? I’m not sure how since I didn’t doing anything with it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I missed it was basic policy. I haven't seen this behavior before - confirm it meets format. I generally do extension_foo for claim format.  If you continue to draw a blank, create a support ticket and include the correlationId.

Comment: Well, after a week of trying it randomly, it updated when I tried it today. Good thing this was not a production app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to create a support ticket with Microsoft today. Before I did that, I tried to update it again and it worked this time. Must have been an Azure problem !